# simple html dom, pick tr only from tbody

Tags: simple-html-dom

I'm trying to grab all the TRs within TBODY from the below table

```
<table id="a">
    <thead>
        <tr>empty</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          content I want is here
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

using this code

```
$html->find('tbody tr');
```

But it will not ignore the empty tr in thead. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed a weird behavior... Even using `>` meaning the direct child, doesnt work!

Check this:

```
$input =  <<<_DATA_
    <table id="a">
        <thead>
            <tr>empty</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              content I want is here
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
_DATA_;

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($input);


foreach($html->find('tbody > tr') as $tr){
    // The parent tag name
    $parentTag = $tr->parent()->tag; 

    echo $parentTag . ' => ' . $tr->plaintext;

    // Make sure the parent tag is 'tbody'
    if( $parentTag == 'tbody' )
        echo ' => OK';

    echo '<br>';
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
thead => empty
tbody => content I want is here => OK
```

So, a workarround would be to test if the parent is equal to the appropriate value as chown above